# How to configure a writable folder inside an application published to Azure App Service using Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm working in an application to obtain some data from a web service, create a text file in the local filesystem send a command to a command line application, obtain the result and then send the results back via the web service.

I need to be able to write to the local file system, read from it and then delete the temporary file. I was reading about bind mounts and volumes but this folder can be delete if a new version of the image is uploaded is just a staging area.

Any ideas how this can be done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using containers in App Service, I believe you will have to link a storage account and mount file shares accordingly. Depending on the OS ([windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage) / [linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage#prerequisites)), the steps vary a bit.

If you are not using containers, then you should be able to access the [temporary file locations](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) for file-based requirements. Do note that the storage available this way is limited and not shared across site instances.